# How to keep the decimal places after a calculation in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database which stores product costs as `(DECIMAL) 9,2` which is named `cost` as a column.

I have created a cart controller which works perfectly. After ensuring the cart has products, I then loop through the content of the product calculating the total cost with the given product and quantity.

```
$total = 0;
foreach(session('cart') as $key => $product)
    $total = $total + (\DB::table('product_list')->where('id', $key)->get()->first()->cost * $product[0]['quantity']);
```

The problem I am getting is that the decimal place is being ignored. If the cost is `150.00`, I have `1` quantity then the total is coming out as `150` without the two decimal places.

I have tried using [`bcmul()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) which is designed for decimal integration with maths but this gives me the same output. I have also tried to use `ROUND($total, 2)` to get the nearest 2 decimal places, if none then `.00` but this hasn't worked either.

Is it possible to ensure that these decimal places are kept after using any mathematically queries or is it possible to add all of the costs together in the SQL Query Builder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to differentiate between data storage, and formatted output shown to human users. The latter is the one you want to modify.

Comment: and you can do that, for example, with `number_format(150,2);`

Comment: The issue is, I need the decimal places to stay (`150.00` in the example case) because I am using Stripe PHP to create payments which expects `15000` to be £150.00. `150` is coming out £1.50 in my Stripe Charge @misorude

Comment: Then you need to multiply it by 100. Decimal points won't change that when passing it into Stripe.

Comment: @RolandStarke After updating it to `$total = $total + number_format((\DB::table('product_list')->where('id', $key)->get()->first()->cost * (int) $product[0]['quantity']), 2);` if I echo `$total` it is still `150` without decimal places. Do I need to use `echo number_format($total, 2)` as well?

Comment: For Stripe, on the charge amount object: `A positive integer in the smallest currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal currency) representing how much to charge.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `number_format()` like this:

```
echo number_format("150",2);
```

it will print: 150.00

Working fiddle [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ca187a86dee00dbc3f170dff774710cc2086a13)

> number_format

Format a number with grouped thousands

Comment: Brilliant, `str_replace('.', '', number_format($total, 2)))` now gives me my desired value of `15000` to use for Stripe. Thank you!

Comment: Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` or `$s = sprintf`to convert a number to a string:

```
printf("%.02f", 150.00);
```

Comment: I do not want to directly print the result. I need to multiple the cost by the quantity and append it to my total variable. `0 + (150.00 * 1)` is the test I am doing but my total variable is now `150` not `150.00` after the calculation.

Comment: A variable can be a string or a float or integer. When you echo a float, the trailing zeroes will disappear. The trailing zeroes only stay when the variable is a string.

Comment: `printf("%.02f", $total)` gives me `150` - The issue is, when I do the calculation, it rounds it to the nearest whole number if the two decimal places are `.00`. I need `150.00` to stay because Stripe expects `15000` so I can use `str_replace()` to achieve this with the decimal.